# Based on uwsim, is it possible to set the friction force of water for the auv?

Tags: ros, force, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on uwsim, is it possible to set the friction force of water for the auv? The auv would drift after the thruster was shut down. I want to set a friction force in order to make the auv stop drifting.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228820/based-on-uwsim,-is-it-possible-to-set-the-friction-force-of-water-for-the-auv?/) by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2016-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The friction force with the water (drag) is already simulated. You can change the paremeters modifying the [.yaml file](https://github.com/uji-ros-pkg/underwater_simulation/blob/indigo-devel/underwater_vehicle_dynamics/config/dynamics_g500.yaml). The parameters used are based on the Fossen dynamics model described in [guidance and control of ocean vehicles](https://books.google.es/books/about/Guidance_and_control_of_ocean_vehicles.html?id=cwJUAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y). You can also check the [UWSim paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6385788&tag=1) where it is explained.

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2016-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) on 2016-03-14**:
Thanks for your suggestion. It is helpful.